# Hamburger menu not working on sub menu pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hope you are enjoying:)
I need little help
My website is working fine but on sub menu pages the hamburger menus not showing up at all. its showing completely fine on all the other pages but on every sub menu page its gone..

http://packsmartinc.com/market-segment/specialty-print-finishing-solutions/
(this is the one of my sub menu page)

Please view my case & let me know. 
Thanks

```
/* Responsive Menu */
.menu-other-style .menu-item:not(.current-menu-item) {
    display: none;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-language-override: normal;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-synthesis: weight style;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30%;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item::before {
    content: "\f054";
}     
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item.open::before {
    content: "\f078";
}

.menu-other-style .current-menu-item a {
    padding: 20px;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item a br {
    display: none;
}

.mobi-submenu-two {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: none;
}
.mobi-submenu-two .menu-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.mobi-submenu-two .menu-item a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 1350px) {

}


---------------------------------------  

.navi--top > li {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.navi--top > li > a {
  height: 100%;
}
.navi--top > li.current-menu-item > a {
  background-color: #95050a;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu {
  background: #d31f26 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  width: 350px;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li:hover .sub-menu,
.navi--top > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(149, 5, 10, 0.7);
}
.sub-menu > li > .sub-menu {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  border-top: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: you should add proper code snippet which should show the actual problem that is happening at your end you need to replicate it here so others can help you out, adding css only wont help.

Comment: hey @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for your reply. basically its problem is on WordPress & I'm new on WordPress so I don't know ho to find actual code that is why I posted only css related to the navigation bar. what should I do next. 
thanks

Comment: does not matter if it is WordPress or any other framework go to view source copy the HTML section for the menu and along with the CSS  and/or Javascript if any and replicate it here, that will make troubleshooting and solving the problem more efficient or if not possible share the live link to the page

Comment: this is my live page where I can face the problem, I face the problem in only mobile devices. on mobile devices the menu is disappear on sub menu pages.

http://packsmartinc.com/market-segment/specialty-print-finishing-solutions/

Comment: try adding `@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) {
#mobile-advanced, .mobile_active.mobile_menu_tablet #advanced_menu_toggle {
display: block;
}
}`

Comment: I just added, but not working, same there

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I just add your code but its still the same... no affect there... What we do now ??